# Under what conditions is the convolution of an input signal with the system's impulse response periodic?

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals, linear-systems

I'm currently solving the following convolution problem from Oppenheimer's book:
[image]

In the solution, it was stated that *"$x(t)$ periodic implies $y(t)$ is periodic"*
So I wondered if it's always the case that if $x(t)$ is periodic then so is the output from the convolution, I tried doing research about this in hope of finding any supporting evidence to this but I couldn't, and "circular convolution" is all around the place.

Comment: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19799/periodicity-of-the-output-of-causal-time-invariant-systems-when-the-input-is-per for a previous discussion about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I wondered if it's always the case that if x(t) is periodic then so is the output from the convolution

Yes, it's always the case. Convolution is a linear operation and linear operations preserve periodicity.

Roughly speaking: any periodic signal consists of a sum of discrete sine waves. The output of an LTI system to a sine wave is also a sine wave at the same frequency. Hence the LTI system preserves the "discreteness" of the original input.

Comment: Alright, is it then safe to say that the output signal will also have the same period? Because I think I also need that fact.

Comment: Yes. LTI systems can't shift frequencies around. The complex exponential is an eigenfunction of an LTI system.

Comment: No. You can construct examples where the output has half, third, fourth ..  the period of the input signal. @MackTuesday: LTI can't shift frequencies but it can eliminate specific ones.

Comment: Of course. I knew I was missing something.

Comment: You picked the wrong one to single out. It's not the linearity that preserves periodicity, it's time-invariance. Linearity is neither sufficient nor necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I am somehow rephrasinge what @Hilmar already answered. In the continuous-time setting, **convolution cannot invent frequencies**. Indeed, there is an intimate relationship between Fourier and convolution, that is not always taught properly. Recently, Michael Bronstein was [Deriving convolution from first principles](https://towardsdatascience.com/deriving-convolution-from-first-principles-4ff124888028)

> Have you ever wondered what is so special about convolution? In this
> post, I derive the convolution from first principles and show that it
> naturally emerges from translational symmetry.

The basic assumptions that a system is linear, and invariant by shift or in time (LTI) imply the concept of convolution. And convolution implies that a sine undergoing an LTI system will still be a sine, albeit with a time-shift (phase change) and amplitude modification (it can even vanish). In other symbols, through an LTI:

$$ \sin(\omega t)\to A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$$

$A$ can be zero, so frequencies can disappear. Yet if  $\sin(\omega t)$ is not present in the original data (no $\omega$), it cannot reappear. Frequency creation from nothing is a feature of nonlinear or time-variant systems.

Comment: Nitpick: frequency creation is a feature of time-variant systems. For example, the system $\text{T}[x(t)] = x(t)\cos(\omega t)$ is linear but it can create new frequencies not present in $x(t)$.

Comment: Interesting post by Bronstein BTW, thanks for linking to it!

Comment: Of course, I was in the state of mind on shift-invariance. Correcting